# Svelte: How to bind a formatted input field to a property

Tags: binding, number-formatting, getter-setter, svelte, input-field

First of all: Svelte is still new to me. I hope the question is not too trivial.

Within a simple component I want to use the content of a **formatted input field** for a calculation.
For example: 
In the input field a Euro amount should be displayed formatted (1.000).
Next to it a text with the amount plus VAT should be displayed (1.190).

How I do this **without formatting** is clear to me. The example looks like this:

```
    export let net;
    export let vat;

    $: gross = net + (net * vat / 100);
    $: grossPretty = gross.toLocaleString('de-DE',{ minimumFractionDigits: 0, maximumFractionDigits: 0 });
```

with a simple markup like this:

```
    <form>
      <label>Net amount</label>
      <input type="text" step="any" bind:value={net} placeholder="Net amount">
    </form>
    <div>
        Gros = {grossPretty} €
    </div>
```

In **vue** i used a computed property. Its **getter** delivers the formatted string and its **setter** takes the formatted string and saves the raw value.
*(In data() I define net, in the computed properties i define netInput. The input field uses netInput as v-model)*.
It looks like this:

```
netInput: {
   get(){
      return this.net.toLocaleString('de-DE',{ minimumFractionDigits: 0, maximumFractionDigits: 0 });
   },
   set(s){
      s = s.replace(/[\D\s._-]+/g, "");
      this.net = Number(s);
   }
}
```

**How can I handle it in svelte?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something somewhat similar, you create another computed variable that stores the deformatted string from the input field and is used in the calculation instead of the direct input

```js
  export let net;
  export let vat;
  $: net_plain = Number(net.replace(/[\D\s._-]+/g, ""));
  $: gross = net_plain + (net_plain * vat / 100);
  $: grossPretty = gross.toLocaleString('de-DE',{ minimumFractionDigits: 0, maximumFractionDigits: 0 });
```

But maybe find a better name for the variable :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Stephane Vanraes I found a solution.

It has not the charm of the vue approach but it's ok. First I inserted 'net_plain'. To have the input field formatted during input, I added an event listener for the keyup event.

```
<input type="text" step="any" bind:value={net} on:keyup={handleKeyUp} placeholder="Net amount">
```

The event is handled from the function handleKeyUp as follows:

```
function handleKeyUp(event){
        if ( window.getSelection().toString() !== '' ) {
            return;
        }
        // ignore arrow keys
        let arrows = [38,40,37,39];
        if ( arrows.includes( event.keyCode)) {
            return;
        }
        let input = event.target.value.replace(/[\D\s._-]+/g, "");
        input = input ? parseInt( input, 10 ) : 0;
        event.target.value = ( input === 0 ) ? "" : input.toLocaleString( "de-DE" );
    }
```

**BUT**: If anyone has a solution using getter and setter I would appreciate the anwer!

Comment: Here's an example using actions that may be helpful:
https://svelte.dev/repl/5c1abf5d24c94960a267124662e11a8d?version=3.44.2